# .getTime when $(document).ready for countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a countdown. Here's the algorithm :

```
var timeFinish, timeStart, timeNow, duration

timeStart <- the time when the document has ready

timeFinish <- timeStart + 1hour

timeNow <- get the time everytime (every second)

duration <- timeFinish - timeNow

output (duration)
```

I deliberately didn't write the algorithm for converting it into second etc (for shortening purpose, and I hope you get what I mean). Here's my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(countdown(), 1000);

  function countdown() {
    var hStart = new Date($(document).ready).getHours;
    var mStart = new Date($(document).ready).getMinutes;
    var sStart = new Date($(document).ready).getSeconds;

    var secondTotalStart = (hStart * 3600) + (mStart * 60) + sStart;
    var secondTotalFinish = secondTotalStart + 3600;

    var hRunning = new Date().getHours;
    var mRunning = new Date().getMinutes;
    var sRunning = new Date().getSeconds;
    var secondTotalRunning = (hRunning * 3600) + (mRunning * 60) + sRunning;

    var duration = secondTotalFinish - secondTotalRunning;

    var h = Math.floor(duration / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(duration % 3600) / 60;
    var s = Math.floor(duration % 3600) % 60;

    $("#countdown").html(h + " h : " + m + " m : " + s + " s");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

And my question is, how to get the timeStart? And is my code wrong?

Comment: This should be setInterval(countdown,1000); also why are you trying to pass $(document).ready to the constructor of Date-object?

Comment: coz i dunno how to get the time when the document has ready :)

Comment: Adding to what @Esko have said, you are calculating the time start every time your loop executes. You should do it just once at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your code so you can look at mistakes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //below line: you must pass countdown as a function
  setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  var dt = new Date(); //get this out of countdown function
  var hStart = dt.getHours();
  var mStart = dt.getMinutes();
  var sStart = dt.getSeconds();
  var secondTotalStart = (hStart * 3600) + (mStart * 60) + sStart;
  var secondTotalFinish = secondTotalStart + 3600;

  function countdown() {
    var cdt = new Date();
    var hRunning = cdt.getHours();
    var mRunning = cdt.getMinutes();
    var sRunning = cdt.getSeconds();
    var secondTotalRunning = (hRunning * 3600) + (mRunning * 60) + sRunning;
    var duration = secondTotalFinish - secondTotalRunning;
    var h = Math.floor(duration / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(duration % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(duration % 3600) % 60;
    $("#countdown").html(h + " h : " + m + " m : " + s + " s");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Why downvote?? This is your answer itself which its problems was solved and works fine!!

Comment: Thanks @Esko for putting the code as inline `snippet`. I've typed it via my mobile phone where I do not have access to the `stackoverflow` code editor on it. putting the external test link (`fiddle`) was because this :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var dTime = new Date(); //need to store the on-load time before set interval as a reference
 setInterval(countdown, 1000);

  function countdown() {
    var hStart = dTime.getHours();//need to get the on-load hr, min and sec from the previously stored time.
    var mStart = dTime.getMinutes();
    var sStart = dTime.getSeconds();


    var secondTotalStart = (hStart * 3600) + (mStart * 60) + sStart;
    var secondTotalFinish = secondTotalStart + 3600;

  var running = new Date()// store the current time into a variable
    var hRunning = running.getHours();
    var mRunning = running.getMinutes();
    var sRunning = running.getSeconds();
    var secondTotalRunning = (hRunning * 3600) + (mRunning * 60) + sRunning;

    var duration = secondTotalFinish - secondTotalRunning;

    var h = Math.floor(duration / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(duration % 3600) / 60;
    var s = Math.floor(duration % 3600) % 60;

    $("#countdown").html(h + " h : " + m + " m : " + s + " s");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Did minor corrections. hope this helps

edit:
added some useful comments.

Comment: Why a downvote?  I just corrected the answer in the same format you wrote. So that you know where all I corrected. If you do not want to mark it as answer, why should you downvote?!

Comment: Probably the asker didn't down voted you. I think someone did it because code (*only*) answers are not so useful, if you don't explain a bit what you did it or why.